# How to get a nested JSON object from a REST response in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making a REST call using the Python requests library as such:

```py
response = requests.get(...)
data = response.json()
```

The JSON returned is complex with lots of nested objects.  Here is a summary:

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://pseudo.com/iam/governance/selfservice/api/v1/accounts"
    }
  ],
  "accounts": [
    {
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://pseudo.com/iam/governance/selfservice/api/v1/accounts"
        }
      ],
      "accountId": "73",
      "userId": "1005",
      "appInstanceId": "1",
      "requestId": "",
      "status": "Provisioning",
      "accountType": "Unknown",
      "policyKey": "",
      "processInstanceKey": "201",
      "provisionedBy": "1",
      "provisionedByMechanism": "Direct Provision",
      "provisionedOnDate": "2016-03-22",
      "riskSummary": 0,
      "accountDescription": "201",
      "validFromDate": "2016-03-22",
      "normalizeData": {
        
      },
      "accountData": {
        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The only library I have imported thus far is `import requests`.

How can I retrieve the value from the key `"accountId"` from the response above?

Is this possible with only the `requests` library or do I need to import the `json` library too?

Comment: `data['accounts'][0]['accountId']`

Comment: What does data["accounts"][0]["accountId"] return? What is output of type(data)?

Comment: @AnanayMital `data["accounts"]` is a list.

Comment: yeah realized that. Thanks to your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
account_id = data['accounts'][0]['accountId']
```

if there could be multiple accounts and some might not have an accountId, you can try this:

```
account_id = next((account['accountId'] for account in data['accounts'] if 'accountId' in account),None)
```

if you want to get all accountIds from the accounts, then try this:

```
account_ids = [account.get('accountId') for account in data['accounts
    ...: ']]
```

Comment: You can replace `account['accountId'] if 'accountId' in account else None ` with `account.get('accountId')`

Comment: yh thanks, it wouldn't work in the second case though

Comment: `account_id = next((account.get('accountId') for account in data['accounts']))`. However it does not make much sense to have a generator expression just to call `next()` one time. Maybe have the generator bind to a name, then call `next()` in a loop so that you consume the generator one item at a time.

Comment: in the second case, i assumed he only wanted the first accountId in any account in the list. hence, i used next with a generator that looks for the first account containing an accountId. the generator only yields items with an accountId, then i used next so that once an accountId was found, the generator is discarded. if i were to use account.get, then if the first item has no 'accountId', the generator would yield None rather than check the next account item

Comment: I know perfectly well how generator works - lazy, etc., but for accessing only one [particular] element it is your first example that is much better - simple, versatile (you can access single element at arbitrary index, etc.). If you have multiple accounts, IMHO it doesn't make sense to return only those who have accountID, but I guess it's up to OP.

Answer (score 2):

`data['accounts']` is list of dicts, so you want to iterate over it or use index to acces specific account.

```
for acc in data['accounts']:
    print(acc['accountId']) # or print(acc.get('accountId'))
```

Working with JSON objects and arrays is no different from working with dicts and list - that is what they are parsed into.